# Which plural form to use when unknown quantity

Tags: nouns, plurality, countability

I'm not super into linguistics so sorry I won't be using the correct terms here. I also only speak English (though I know tiny bits of a few languages). Also sorry if this is a duplicate, I found it difficult to come up with apt search terms. And a final sorry for getting somewhat programming-technical in this post.

All that said, my problem is hopefully quite simple to explain:

I am building a web site administration area, let's say I have articles, and each article can have one or more authors. The administration area will show, at a glance, the authors of a given article:

```
Article Title | Date Posted | Authors
--------------|-----------------------------------
Article #1    | 2014-03-10  | Alice Abrahams
Article #2    | 2014-03-12  | Bob Roberts, Constance Chamberlain
Article #3    | 2014-03-18  | Bob Roberts
```

My question comes because I'm trying to internationalise my application. So far I've managed to get away with allowing my translation framework (Symfony's via Laravel) sort that out for me by doing a `choice` style translation when I need to refer to `1 X`/`6 Ys` and a simple `translate` when just translating messages directly.

So, for the column titles (like `Article Title` in this example), I can just iterate through the display fields and `trans()` the field name (presuming a model's author has entered the correct translations given the convention that the key is the field name). But `Authors` is defined as a relationship on the article model, and thus I want to be able to automatically retrieve the translation of the related model and then put it into its plural form for this column heading.

In English, it's trivial to do this - just use the plural. However, there are languages out there that have multiple plural forms. Russian has the 1, 2 and 3+ form, and I think there are some that have 1, 2, 3, 4+. As such, which plural form is the correct one for this kind of 'uncounted plural'? (As a side question, what do these languages do for the 0 form? Is it counted as a plural like it is in English? Is it one of the categories already mentioned (2, 3+) or its own category?)

I'm aware it could be argued that my premise is somewhat lacking, and that I could use "Author(s)" in the English form (though, again, it's not always as simple in other languages to indicate that something could be singular or plural). Either way, let's ignore that for now, and assume the plural is a good fit. What is the correct way to form the plural I want in the `Authors` column? Or is it best left to the article model's author to decide what this word should be, the same way they will be for the model's own fields?

I hope the references to programming don't confuse my question too much. I just wanted to explain why I'm asking the question I'm asking from a background of knowing nothing about the specific target language.

---

Edit based on the first comment below, I felt it was worth clarifying my question here as the above is somewhat wordy:

Okay so I understand that the 'final' form is always considered the plural (and all others are specific numerical forms). So my questions are below:

- Does this mean that, in my example, the 'unknown count' form I should use is the plural (i.e. final form of whichever language to which the application is set)?
- Do different languages/cultures have different rules for which to use (maybe some always use the singular in this case)?
- If that's the case, is there a term for this form that linguists use to refer to it in all languages?
- If anyone has a background in computer-based translation, what's the way to specify that I wish to use this form to a translation provider?

Comment: The "1 form" is a singular and refers to a group of 1, the "2 form" is a dual and refers to a group of 2, etc. The plural is only the form that is actually used for a greater number of individuals. If there's a form that can be used for a smaller number of individuals and that can be used for a larger group, then the latter is a plural.

Comment: @robert thanks for trying to help me out. I've edited my post to reflect this knowledge you've provided, but it still didn't seem to answer my question, so I've also clarified my questions below the main post.

Comment: For this kind of application, there are a lot of other ways in which nouns can be inflected besides just singular vs plural. Word order can also change in some languages.

Comment: So there's not a concise answer to my question (at least in terms of a linguistic rule of thumb)? I guess, therefore, the answer is to leave these translations up to a translator rather than trying to automatically work one out from rules, right?